# svg showing up as red in safari with dynamic gradients in angular 2

Tags: angular, svg, safari

I'm creating a dynamic bar chart, which is filled to a point, with a linear gradient at the top which is also dynamic.  I've been experiencing multiple issues with safari like having only read only properties for styles, and read only svg properties so I've been changing this for a while trying to get it to work.

The graph shows up well on chrome and firefox, but when in safari, it shows the general red fill without any gradient.  but, if I take the html that was created and throw it into something like w3schools, I can see the graph gradients correctly.  Is what i'm trying to do just not possible in safari?

Heres some of my code:

```
//after view is checked, run this.
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    let id;
    if(this.bars != undefined && this.bars.length > 0){
      id = "chartWithDynamicWidth" + "-" + this.bars[0].id;
    }else{
      return;
    }
    //chartWithDynamicWidth
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element){
      element.style.width = this.bars[this.bars.length-1].x + this.bars[this.bars.length-1].width +12;
      if(this.type == 'manage' ){//because svg class, isn't like other classes. 
        element.className['baseVal']  = 'chart style-fix-chart-manage'
      }else{
        element.className['baseVal']  = 'chart style-fix-chart-not-manage'
      }
    }
    for(let i = 0; i< this.bars.length; i++){
      let bar = this.bars[i];
      let color = bar.color;
        this.fillInTheGraphGradient(bar, [color]);
    }
  }
  fillInTheGraphGradient(bar, colors){
    let color, id, element;
    for(let j = 0; j< colors.length; j++){
      color = colors[j];
      id = 'color-bar-'+color+'-' + bar.id;
      element = document.getElementById(id);
      if(element){
        element.style.fill = 'url(#MyGradient-bar-'+color+'-' + bar.id + ')';
      }else{
        //console.log('no element with id', id);
      }
      id = 'MyGradient-stop2-'+color+'-' + bar.id;
      element = document.getElementById(id);
      if(element){
        element.setAttribute("offset", (100 / bar.level) * (2 * bar.leeway) + '%');
        element.setAttribute("stop-color", color);
      }else{
        console.log('no element with id', id);
      }
    }
  }


//html.
<svg  *ngIf=" !inProggress || true"
                [id]="'chartWithDynamicWidth'+'-' + bars[0].id"
                aria-labelledby="title desc" 
                role="img"  
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
            >
                <g *ngFor="let bar of bars; let i = index;">
                    <g class="background-bar " (mouseover)='ShowTooltip(i,bar.color)' (mouseleave)='HideTooltip()'>
                        <rect 
                            [attr.width]="bar.bgWidth" 
                            height="100" 
                            [attr.y]="bar.bgY" 
                            [attr.x]="bar.bgX" 
                            [id]="'back-bar-'+bar.color+'-' + bar.id"
                        >
                        </rect>
                    </g>
                    <g *ngIf="bar.color != 'Tri-color'">
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient [id]="'MyGradient-bar-'+bar.color+'-' + bar.id" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                                <stop  offset="0%" stop-color="#fff"  />
                                <stop [id]="'MyGradient-stop2-'+bar.color+'-' + bar.id" />
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <g  [attr.class]="bar.paused ? 'bar bar-paused' : 'bar'" (mouseover)='ShowTooltip(i,bar.color)' (mouseleave)='HideTooltip()'>
                            <rect 
                                [attr.width]="bar.width" 
                                [attr.height]="bar.height" 
                                [attr.y]="bar.y" 
                                [attr.x]="bar.x" 
                                [id]="'color-bar-'+bar.color+'-' + bar.id"
                            ></rect>
                            <text [attr.x]="bar.textX" [attr.y]="bar.textY" dy=".35em" class="graph-text"
                                >{{bar.color}}</text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                  </g>
          </svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide the generated HTML/SVG?

Comment: It's at the bottom, after //html;  It seems to be impossible, unless you have xhtml, but I don't know how, don't know if it's possible to make angular2 xhtml compatible.  So i'm scrapping the svg, and going to create the charts with divs to make it easier for browser compatibility, and am using the html background gradient style property.

Comment: (Sorry - I meant the actual HTML/SVG generated (from the inspector) - I don't know Angular, but was going to take a whack at debugging the output.)

Comment: Yea, sorry, don't have it anymore.  But the result does work, if i put the resulting svg not the browser it renders just fine.  It has something to do with safari not liking dynamic linear gradients it seems.  I've read on other posts that it works if your html is instead xhtml, but making angular xml compatible seems like a very large headache, and time consumeing.  Now i'm just using divs and dynamically creating normal css linear gradients and it's working great in all browsers.